# How to convert the datasets of Spark Row into string?

Tags: java, string, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have written the code to access the Hive table using SparkSQL. Here is the code:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("Java Spark Hive Example")
        .master("local[*]")
        .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083")
        .enableHiveSupport()
        .getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> df =  spark.sql("select survey_response_value from health").toDF();
df.show();
```

I would like to know how I can convert the complete output to String or String array? As I am trying to work with another module where only I can pass String or String type Array values.
I have tried other methods like `.toString` or typecast to String values. But did not worked for me.
Kindly let me know how I can convert the DataSet values to String?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is the sample code in Java.

```
public class SparkSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("SparkSample")
            .master("local[*]")
            .getOrCreate();
    //create df
    List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
    Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataset(myList, Encoders.STRING()).toDF();
    df.show();
    //using df.as
    List<String> listOne = df.as(Encoders.STRING()).collectAsList();
    System.out.println(listOne);
    //using df.map
    List<String> listTwo = df.map(row -> row.mkString(), Encoders.STRING()).collectAsList();
    System.out.println(listTwo);
  }
}
```

"row" is java 8 lambda parameter. Please check [developer.com/java/start-using-java-lambda-expressions.html](http://www.developer.com/java/start-using-java-lambda-expressions.html)

Comment: Please can you explain me what is this `row` in the program? You code looks pretty optimized to me.

Comment: "row" is java 8 lambda parameter. Please check http://www.developer.com/java/start-using-java-lambda-expressions.html

Comment: Its perfect. Thanks.

Comment: i am getting this error when i used df.as.  Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Try to map struct<***my column names here***> to Tuple1, but failed as the number of fields does not line up.;

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [`map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@map[U](func:T=>U)(implicitevidence$6:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[U]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U]) function to convert every row into a string, e.g.:

```
df.map(row => row.mkString())
```

Instead of just [`mkString`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html#mkString()) you can of course do more sophisticated work

The [`collect`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#collect()) method then can retreive the whole thing into an array

```
val strings = df.map(row => row.mkString()).collect
```

(This is the Scala syntax, I think in Java it's quite similar)

Comment: It didn't work, my friend. Can you help me with java, instead of Scala. i know the syntax are a bit similar, but there are other problems while we use java instead of Scala

Comment: @Jaffer Java8 syntax should be very similar

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you for your advise. It helped.

Comment: Does this work for a row with multiple columns. or we need row encoder etc for it

Comment: It also works for rows with multiple columns. You can also pass a separator string to `mkString` to separate the columns.

Comment: I had to use "df.map(row => row.mkString)"  without the () for it to work (Scala 3)

Answer (score 3):

to put as a single string, from sparkSession you can do:

```
sparkSession.read.textFile(filePath).collect.mkString
```

assuming your Dataset is of type String: Dataset[String]

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to read the dataset line by line, then you can use the iterator over the dataset:

```
 Dataset<Row>csv=session.read().format("csv").option("sep",",").option("inferSchema",true).option("escape, "\"").option("header", true).option("multiline",true).load(users/abc/....);

for(Iterator<Row> iter = csv.toLocalIterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    String item = (iter.next()).toString();
    System.out.println(item.toString());    
}
```